# How to define unicode ranges by properties/identifiers in c++ for PEGTL

Tags: c++, utf-8, peg

With PEGTL (https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL), which is a template based C++11 header-only PEG library, I can define ranges for unicode characters like this:

- utf8::range<0x0, 0x10FF> //All UTF8 Characters
- utf8::range<0x41, 0x5A, 0x61, 0x7A> //UTF8 0x41-0x5A[A-Z] and 0x61-0x7A[a-z]

Now with UTF8 there is this properties categorisation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) with which I could do something like [:Lu:] or [:ID_Start:] and get a set/range of characters.

Now, since I'm working with c++ templates, I need those ranges at compile time. In my opinion I have the following options:

1. Discover that PEGTL has itself the possibility to look up [:ID_Start:] or [:Lu:]
2. Find a c++ preprocessor library, that allows such queries at compile time
3. Get an Application/Online Service, where I can perform those queries and get ranges (as shown above), which I can then paste in my code.

This also represents the order of the solutions I prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PEGTL](https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/) uses rules to match characters, not return sets of characters. If you'd like to match characters with certain Unicode character properties, you could create a [custom rule](https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/blob/master/doc/Rules-and-Grammars.md#creating-new-rules) and implement it with the help of some Unicode library, e.g. [ICU](http://icu-project.org/). It provides methods to test codepoints for various properties, see [this link](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/properties).

Here's a complete example program:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#include <unicode/uchar.h>

#include <tao/pegtl.hpp>

using namespace tao::TAO_PEGTL_NAMESPACE;  // NOLINT

namespace test
{
   template< UProperty P >
   struct icu_has_binary_property
   {
      using analyze_t = analysis::generic< analysis::rule_type::ANY >;

      template< typename Input >
      static bool match( Input& in )
      {
         // this assumes the input is UTF8, adapt as necessary
         const auto r = internal::peek_utf8::peek( in );
         // if a code point is available, the size is >0
         if( r.size != 0 ) {
            // check the property
            if( u_hasBinaryProperty( r.data, P ) ) {
               // if it matches, consume the character
               in.bump( r.size );
               return true;
            }
         }
         return false;
      }
   };

   using icu_lower = icu_has_binary_property< UCHAR_LOWERCASE >;
   using icu_upper = icu_has_binary_property< UCHAR_UPPERCASE >;

   // clang-format off
   struct grammar : seq< icu_upper, plus< icu_lower >, eof > {};
   // clang-format on
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   for( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) {
      argv_input<> in( argv, i );
      std::cout << argv[ i ] << " matches: " << std::boolalpha << parse< test::grammar >( in ) << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Now I can compile and run it:

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -Ipegtl/include icu.cpp -licuuc -licudata -o icu
$ ./icu Ďánîel DánÎel
Ďánîel matches: true
DánÎel matches: false
$
```

---

**EDIT:** I've added the [ICU rules](https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/blob/master/doc/Rule-Reference.md#icu-rules) (lots of them) to the PEGTL. As they require ICU, an external dependency, I've put them in the `contrib`-section.